# How to disable 301 redirection in plesk for Domain-Alias via API

Tags: plesk

I using **https://example.com:8443/enterprise/control/agent.php** to call plesk Api using some Xml content, what I do is create and manage my domains and sites.
For some reason I need Create a Site-Alias(domain-alias) for my domain without 301 redirection.I can do it from plesk panel as I note in Image attached. But I don't know how to set it with xml.
This my xml that I post via API :

```
<packet version="1.6.7.0">
  <site-alias>
    <create>
      <pref>
        <web>1</web>
        <mail>0</mail>
        <tomcat>0</tomcat>
      </pref>
      <site-id>104</site-id>
      <name>mysub.myotherexample.com</name>
    </create>
  </site-alias>
</packet>
```

Note that I have two domain name, **example.com** and **myotherexample.com** .I want add domain-alias **mysub.myotherexample.com** which is an alias for **example.com**.

I need some setting like what you see in Image.But my xml also enabled 301 redirection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `seo-redirect` option https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/17.0/api-rpc/reference/managing-site-aliases/site-alias-settings.33538/ :

```
<packet version="1.6.7.0">
  <site-alias>
    <create>
      <pref>
        <web>1</web>
        <mail>0</mail>
        <tomcat>0</tomcat>
        <seo-redirect>0</seo-redirect>
      </pref>
      <site-id>104</site-id>
      <name>mysub.myotherexample.com</name>
    </create>
  </site-alias>
</packet>
```